# How to resolve 'recycle IIS application pool error in vbScript website'?

Tags: iis, vbscript, garbage-collection, asp-classic, application-pool

This application needs to be recycled at least 3 times a day, currently it's a very big problem. This is not a large-scale logical application, it is primarily used for uploading and downloading documents and updating some data.  Any guess please let me know

How to solve this problem, without changing the application pool recycle time? When I recycle periodically, users logout there login session, which is also a big problem

Comment: Persist the session state using a database, that way you can control the session state and not rely on the ASP in-memory session persistence.

Answer (score -1):

Which session mode are you using in iis? If you have used the default InProc mode for SessionState persistence, any data you add to the session dictionary in server code will be lost during application pool recycling. The next time your code accesses an entry in the SessionState dictionary, it will return null.

Therefore, I suggest that you can use SQLServer mode. SQLServer mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. Using this mode ensures that session state is preserved across web application restarts (including application pool recycling) and also makes session state available to multiple web servers in the web farm.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
     <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
        sqlConnectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;data
        source=SampleSqlServer;" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178586(v=vs.140)) to get more details about iis session state mode.

Comment: That’s ASP.Net not Classic ASP, there is no "SQL Server mode" built-in for Classic ASP (see the duplicate target).